# Filtering flatilist with several items

Tags: reactjs, filter, react-native, flatlist

I am learning React Native by building a RideSharing app. I have a function that allows the user to filter a `FlatList` component with several ride and each one of them has different `items` associated to, sutch as date, number of passengers, cost, etc... And `filteredDate`, `filteredPassangers`, `filteredCost` are state variables that allow the user to choose how he wishes to filter.

I wrote the function that filters the data like this:

```
function filter() {
        const newData1 = lists.filter(
            item => {
                return item.date === filteredDate,
                   item.To === filteredTo,
                   item.passangers === filteredPassangers,
                   item.date === filteredDate,
                   item.cost3 === filteredCost  
            })  
         props.setLists(newData1),  


        //... 
    }
```

However, when I change the state for more than one variable, it doesn't return any ride component what so ever.

How can I code this in order to filter through multiple items at a time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inside your comparison statement you have separated them with comma. That way only the last statement is being evaluated that is `item.cost3 === filteredCost`

you can filter them using `or ( || )` operator like this

```
item.date === filteredDate ||
item.To === filteredTo ||
item.passangers === filteredPassangers ||
item.date === filteredDate ||
item.cost3 === filteredCost
```

that way if any of your conditions are true it will return true.

Comment: Ok, I didn't know about this. But I when I try to filter two values at the same time and one of them doesn't exist it still returns the the component which the first value is true. How do I change this?

Comment: you can do something like this  (item.date && item.date === filteredDate ) in each of the condition

Comment: I replaced it and it still does the same effect. Plus, whenever I filter by cost state it simple shows anything... Do you know why?

Comment: can you create a sandbox so that i can debug your code ?

Comment: How do I create a sandbox sir?

Comment: add your project code to this link https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-snow-dqbbc?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221927/discussion-between-tiago-and-mohammad-faisal).